# How to set enumitem for theorem environment?

Tags: enumerate, theorems, enumitem

I currently have the following `enumitem` pattern for theorems:

```
\begin{theorem}
text
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
\item text 1
\item text 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

which yields

[image]

Is there a way I make this label automatic for every `enumerate` environment nested in the `theorem` environment so I don't need to type the label in each time? More specifically, is there a way to make a preset for `enumerate` in specific environments? It is not necessary to use `enumitem` if I can reproduce the same "indenting" for `enumerate` in the `theorem` environment.

Comment: If you use a special `enumtheo` list, i.e. `\newlist{enumtheo}{enumerate}{1} and say `\setlist[enumtheo]{label={(\arabic*)}]`and then write `enumtheo` instead of `enumerate` this should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The label options of the `enumerate` environment can be set inside the theorem environment right at its start with `\AtBeginEnvironment` from `etoolbox` and `\setlist[enumerate]`.

This does not change the way `enumerate` environments are numbered outside of theorem!

Another way is to use a special `enumtheo` list with `\newlist` and the same settings for `enumtheo` as would have done with `enumerate` and apply `enumtheo` instead of `enumerate` inside the theorems (I've used another theorem environment just for preventing interference between `enumerate` and `enumtheo`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{othertheorem}{Other Theorem}

\newlist{enumtheo}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumtheo]{label={(\arabic*)}}


\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{%
  \setlist[enumerate]{label={(\arabic*)}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text 1
\item text 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Foo
\end{enumerate}

\begin{theorem}
Just another theorem
\begin{enumerate}
\item text 1
\item text 2
\item text 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{othertheorem}
Yet another theorem
\begin{enumtheo}
\item text 1
\item text 2
\item text 3
\end{enumtheo}
\end{othertheorem}


\end{document}
```

**Changed with a loop running `\foreach` for more than just one theorem - like environment**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}

\newtheorem{foobar}{Foobar}


\foreach \theoremenv in {theorem,foo,foobar} {
  \AtBeginEnvironment{\theoremenv}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{label={(\arabic*)}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item text 1
\item text 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Outer enumerate
\end{enumerate}

\begin{foo}
The foo
\begin{enumerate}
\item text 1
\item text 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{foo}

\begin{foobar}
Yet another theorem named foobar
\begin{enumerate}
\item text 1
\item text 2
\item text 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{foobar}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to do this for all defined `\newtheorem` environments or would I have to type the command for all of them individually?

Comment: @TheMonkey: See the 2nd example at the end, using a `\foreach` loop over some selected theorem environments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I now have an `enumerate` nested inside of an `enumerate`, so I went ahead and changed the label to `\setlist[enumerate]{label*={(\arabic*)}}` but that yields `(1)(1)` instead of the desired `(1.1)`. Is there a fix around this?

Comment: `label*` prepends  the 2nd level number with the 1st level, which already has `(...)`, so that's no wonder that `()()` appears in the end. You need `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*)}]` -- using such enclosing styles with `()` or `[]` is tricky and not always recommended. `enumitem` can't know that you want the `()` only for the full numbering of 2nd the level and not for every  level number as you obtained by your method, i.e. (1)(1)