# Set the style of `enumerate` labels to "one-level-down" inside theorem-type environments

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I would like to set the style of `enumerate` labels inside theorem-type environments as that of the labels outside theorem environments but "one-level-down". That is, a level-1 label inside a theorem would look like a level-2 label outside, and a level-2 label inside a theorem would look like a level-3 label outside, and so on. How to do this "neatly"?

In the following MWE I can change the style of labels at different levels, but I do not want to change them into arbitrary styles, but exactly one-level-down from that of the default styles of the document class.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]

%below changes enumerate label styles in theorem environments.
%See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413862/9789
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \theoremenv in {theorem,proposition,lemma} {
  \AtBeginEnvironment{\theoremenv}{%
        \setlist[enumerate,1]{ref={\alph*},label={(\alph*)}}
        \setlist[enumerate,2]{ref={\roman*},label={\roman*.}}
        \setlist[enumerate,3]{ref={\Alph*},label={\Alph*.}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem. It has a few parts:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The first thing
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item The first part of the first thing
        \item The second part of the second thing
    \end{enumerate}
    \item The second thing
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The list depth is handled using the `\@listdepth` counter. You would need to add `\global\advance\@listdepth\@ne` to the begin environment and `\global\advance\@listdepth\m@ne` to the end environment to emulate the adjustment in list depth that you have from nested lists. Note that this will apply to both enumerate and itemize lists.

(and of course you'll need to do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to access the commands with `@` in the names.

Comment: Thank you. I inserted the command but LaTeX reports an error "You can't use `\spacefactor' after \advance. \begin{theorem}". Could you please provide an MWE?